# typescript optional chaining with object destructuring

Tags: typescript

I've just updated `typescript` to `3.7.4` and I am trying to edit my code.

I have a simple code

```
interface Test
  event: {
    queryStringParameters: { [name: string]: string } | null;
  }
}
const test:Test = (event) => {
  // const { no } = event?.queryStringParameters; //Property 'no' does not exist on type '{ [name: string]: string; } | null'.ts(2339)
  const no = event?.queryStringParameters?.no; //It works but I want to use above that.
  ...
}
```

I want to use the `optional chaining` with `destructuring`.

Is it available feature now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because queryStringParameters can be null, and the `null` object does not contain the property `no`. You will need to use a [null coalescing operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#nullish-coalescing) for that:

```
const { no } = event?.queryStringParameters ?? { no: null };
```

Note that the `??` operator is currently only available via **TypeScript 3.7+** is not yet a standard JS operator as of now. See related discussion on TypeScripts repo for more details: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26578